# R error: fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns+ singularity error

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, fixed-effects-model, error-message

[image]I am trying to build a `lmer` model of my study comparing performance accuracies of bilinguals and monolinguals on a memory task. My dependent variable is the accuracy of correct trials and independent ones are language group, number of trials, as well as age and gender. I do not know if age and gender should be random or not. However, when I try to build a model with theses variables, I get the rank deficiency error. I am guessing it has to do with the fact that in the accuracy column there are many "0" values. These values are important and are the core of my study as they indicate participants did not fully complete any of the trials successfully and this is the basis of comparison between the groups.

Here is the model + errors (I had previously ran other models with no zeroes in the columns and this error did not appear).

```r
model7 <- lmer(CorrTrialsNum_percent_c ~ Language_Group + 
       gender.response + (1|participant), data= Data)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

model8  <- lmer(CorrTrialsNum_percent_c ~ 
    Language_Group*gender.response + (1|participant), data= Data)

>fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients
    boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
    
anova(model7_c, model8_c)
        #refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)
```

How can I fix this and get rid of rank deficiency? I am not very familiar with R so simple and clear step-by-step explanations would be helpful.

Should I just ignore this error? I am scared that it is dropping the "0" values from my analysis.

[image]

Comment: Couple of thoughts: 1. could you post a snippet of the actual data? That would probably make it easier to see what might be going on. This error often appears when you have two terms using the exact same information from data (though it can appear for other reasons). 2. Could you post the output you get from the model(s)? What is the random intercept for "participant"? 3. It's possible that you just can't use a linear model with many zeros in the outcome, unfortunately. A censored/tobit regression might work.

Comment: Thanks for the censored regression solution! I will try it. I have looked it up and it is exactly the issue with my data as I have a lot of zeroes and those are actual important data points as my whole hypothesis includes and predicts these values. I am guessing lmer penalizes for this. I will post a snippet here later of my data but as I said I have a lot of zeroes as accuracy percentages (meaning participants made 100% mistakes).

Comment: I think censored regression will work! I asked to see the data because from a snippet it's easy to see whether there's a data structure issue that may cause the rank deficiency, and to see the output because a typical reason for singular fit in lmer is near-zero cluster-related variance, but in your case both errors may have been caused by the number of zeros.

Comment: Hi Sointu, I have provided a quick picture of my dataset. Please let me know if that helps. Also, I am not sure how to carry out censored regression in R. Is it the same as Tobit? Which package would that be?

Comment: Sorry Nadine, I don't regularly use censored regression so I didn't realize there actually isn't an R package available that handles *multilevel* censored regression. Stan and Stata can do that though - maybe check them out? There is quite good guide for the Stata procedure at least : https://www.stata.com/features/overview/multilevel-tobit-models/    And yes, censored and Tobit regression usually mean the same procedure.